# Find the Fourier series of the 3l-periodic function

Tags: fourier-series, periodic-functions, fast-fourier-transform

[Question 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1fHf.png)

Find the Fourier series of the 3l-periodic function on the image above:

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.